# Definition of $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ choosing value of $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

On what curve is $\arg (z)$ discontinuous if it is defined as the value of $Arg(z)$ satisfing the inequality:
$$|z|-2\pi<\operatorname{Arg}(z)\leq|z|$$

would it be a ray from the origin with argument equal to $|z|$? Could somebody clarify this for me?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29) has the convention the other way around: $\operatorname{Arg}$ is a canonical value, and $\arg$ is the set of all values. (I followed your convention in my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's discontinuous on the curve $\operatorname{Arg}(z)=|z|$. This is an [Archimedean spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).